# Why can't I change php.ini?

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I hosted a WordPress website on Ubuntu 20.04 via LAMP. Now when I try to install a theme, "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini." this error occurs. I can't save by changing upload_max_filesize in /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini.

[As you can see in the image below, it says Read Only next to the name of the php.ini file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI51h.png)

Now how can I edit this file?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit this file as root user.
From terminal:

```
sudoedit /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are uploading files via the command line interface (CLI), this may not be the file you’re looking for. Apache uses the `php.ini` file found in `/etc/php/7.4/apache2`.

1. SSH into to your server (if you’re not already connected)
2. Edit the file with your preferred text editor and `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
   ```

   If you choose to use `vi` like in the example above, you can:

   1. find the configuration value quickly by typing <kbd>?</kbd>, then the value name: `upload_max_filesize`
   2. Set `vi` to “edit mode” by pressing <kbd>I</kbd>
   3. Change the value to something you prefer, such as `128M`
3. Save the file

   If you are using `vi`, you can:

   1. Exit “edit mode” by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>
   2. Issue the command to **W**rite the file and **Q**uit the editor: <kbd>:</kbd> ⇢ <kbd>W</kbd> ⇢ <kbd>Q</kbd>
4. Restart the web server:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

That’s all there is to it